# Custom styling for the d3 treemap tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with the d3.js treemap layout . Find my code link here https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-wfbtg. The tooltip consists of the hierarchy like **flare/vis 436777** but I need only the Label and the total count or value like **vis 436777** .
Current tooltip
[image]

Finally added custom tooltip but the tooltip sticks on the canvas on click of a segment rect. Added th screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and found out that you have written a function called "name" where you are finding ancestors and joining them. Please found below my finding and code you need to write to fulfill your requirement. Add the CSS to styles.css and replace your class Treegraph with the below class.

```js
class Treegraph extends React.Component {
  state = {
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };
  createTreeChart = () => {
    const width = 550;
    const height = 500;
    const padding = 60;
    const format = d3.format(",d");
    const name = d =>
      d
      .ancestors()
      .reverse()
      .map(d => d.data.segment)
      .join(" / ");
    // const name = d => d.data.segment;
    function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
      for (const child of node.children) {
        child.x0 = x0 + (child.x0 / width) * (x1 - x0);
        child.x1 = x0 + (child.x1 / width) * (x1 - x0);
        child.y0 = y0 + (child.y0 / height) * (y1 - y0);
        child.y1 = y0 + (child.y1 / height) * (y1 - y0);
      }
    }
    const treemap = data =>
      d3.treemap().tile(tile)(
        d3
        .hierarchy(data)
        .sum(d => d.value)
        .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
      );
    const svg = d3
      .select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
      .style("font", "16px sans-serif");

    const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

    // const svg = d3
    //   .create("svg")
    //   .select("#chart")
    //   .append("svg")
    //   .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
    //   .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

    let group = svg.append("g").call(render, treemap(data));

    function render(group, root) {
      const node = group
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(root.children.concat(root))
        .join("g");

      node
        .filter(d => (d === root ? d.parent : d.children))
        .attr("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", d => (d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d)));

      //node.append("title").text(d => `${name(d)}\n(${format(d.data.count)})`);
      var tool = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "toolTip");

      d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + 300 + "px");
      d3.select(self.frameElement).style("width", width + 20 + "px");

      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = "leaf"))
        .attr("fill", d =>
          d === root ? "#fff" : d.children ? "#045c79" : "#045c79"
        )
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .on("mousemove", function(d) {
          tool.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
          tool.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 20 + "px");
          tool.style("display", "inline-block");
          tool.html(`${d.data.segment}<br />(${format(d.data.count)})`);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tool.style("display", "none");
        });

      node
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = "clip"))
        .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
        .attr("font-weight", d => (d === root ? "bold" : null))
        .attr("font-size", d => {
          if (d === root) return "0.8em";
          const width = x(d.x1) - x(d.x0),
            height = y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
          return Math.max(
            Math.min(
              width / 5,
              height / 2,
              Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height) / 25
            ),
            9
          );
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", d => (d === root ? null : "middle"))
        .attr("transform", d =>
          d === root ?
          null :
          `translate(${(x(d.x1) - x(d.x0)) / 2}, ${(y(d.y1) - y(d.y0)) /
                2})`
        )
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .data(d =>
          d === root ?
          name(d).split(/(?=\/)/g) :
          d.value < 2 ?
          `${d.data.segment.substring(0, 3)}...`.split(/(\s+)/) :
          d.data.segment.split(/(\s+)/).concat(format(d.data.count))
        )
        .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr(
          "y",
          (d, i, nodes) =>
          `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + (i - nodes.length / 2) * 0.9}em`
        )
        // .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, nodes) =>
        //   i === nodes.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null
        // )
        // .attr("font-weight", (d, i, nodes) =>
        //   i === nodes.length - 1 ? "normal" : null
        // )
        .text(d => d);
      node
        .selectAll("text")
        .classed("text-title", d => d === root)
        .classed("text-tile", d => d !== root)
        .filter(d => d === root)
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .attr("y", "1.1em")
        .attr("x", undefined);
      group.call(position, root);
    }

    function position(group, root) {
      group
        .selectAll("g")
        .attr("transform", d =>
          d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`
        )
        .select("rect")
        .attr("width", d => (d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0)))
        .attr("height", d => (d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0)));
    }

    // When zooming in, draw the new nodes on top, and fade them in.
    function zoomin(d) {
      x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
      y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.append("g").call(render, d));
      svg
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t =>
          group0
          .transition(t)
          .remove()
          .call(position, d.parent)
        )
        .call(t =>
          group1
          .transition(t)
          .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
          .call(position, d)
        );
    }

    // When zooming out, draw the old nodes on top, and fade them out.
    function zoomout(d) {
      x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
      y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent));
      svg
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t =>
          group0
          .transition(t)
          .remove()
          .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
          .call(position, d)
        )
        .call(t => group1.transition(t).call(position, d.parent));
    }

    return svg.node();
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createTreeChart();
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      React.Fragment >
      <
      div id = "chart" / >
      <
      /React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
  color: black;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: but it will change the hierarchy title also

Comment: Can you please help me knowing one thing. Have you implemented any tooltip in treemap or are you using default tooltip because i am not able to black colored tooltip.

Comment: its the default one used for d3 treemap layout

Comment: Then in that case you cannot change it. As you are using complete hierarchy  name for labeling, so the tooltip will also show complete hierarchy. 
If you want to show custom label on tooltip, then you have to implement a custom tooltip.

Comment: that's what I asked for . Custom tooltip is possible for this implementation ?

Comment: Yes we can, updated the code with custom tooltip. Please let me know if need any more assistance.

Comment: that's great! but the tooltip sometimes sticks on the canvas on click of a segment. Did  you notice that ? Updated the question with the screenshot

Comment: Also the window resizing and shaking when we move the cursor to the rightmost segment because of the tooltip.